# How to combine Javas Builder pattern with Scala case class with optional fields?

Tags: java, scala, builder-pattern

In Scala you often use Java APIs which use the Builder pattern, e.g Google Maps Java Client (used in the example below).

I use a Scala case class in our app to gather all values that I will use then for the Builder pattern of the Java API. I design optional values of the Builder API, idiomatically with Scalas Option type.
However I scratch my head how to do this nicer than this example:

```
case class WlanHint(
    mac: String,
    signalStrength: Option[Int],
    age: Option[Int],
    channel: Option[Int],
    signalToNoiseRatio: Option[Int]
)
val builder = WifiAccessPoint.WifiAccessPointBuilder().MacAddress(wlanHint.mac)
val b       = wlanHint.signalStrength.map(signalStrength => builder.SignalStrength(signalStrength)).getOrElse(builder)
val b2      = wlanHint.age.map(age => b.Age(age)).getOrElse(b)
val b3      = wlanHint.channel.map(channel => b2.Channel(channel)).getOrElse(b2)
val b4      = wlanHint.signalToNoiseRatio.map(signalToNoiseRatio => b3.SignalToNoiseRatio(signalToNoiseRatio)).getOrElse(b3)
// TODO is there a better way to do this above?
b4.createWifiAccessPoint())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the builder calls within the `case class` as *methods* and also (since a Java builder is typically mutable) use the `foreach` method on `Option`:

```scala
case class WlanHint(
  mac: String,
  signalStrength: Option[Int],
  age: Option[Int],
  channel: Option[Int],
  signalToNoiseRatio: Option[Int]
) {
  def asWifiAccessPoint: WifiAccessPoint = { // guessing about return type...
    val builder = WifiAccessPoint.WifiAccessPointBuilder().MacAddress(mac)
    
    // The ()s may not be needed if not warning about a discarded value...
    signalStrength.foreach { ss => builder.SignalStrength(ss); () }
    age.foreach { a => builder.Age(a); () }
    channel.foreach { c => builder.Channel(c); () }
    signalToNoiseRatio.foreach { snr => builder.SignalToNoiseRatio(snr); () }

    builder.createWifiAccessPoint()
  }
}
```

The first `foreach` in this example ends up being effectively the same as:

```scala
if (signalStrength.isDefined) {
  builder.SignalStrength(signalStrength.get)
}
```

If `WlanHint` is only intended to reify the arguments to the builder, it might make sense to have it be a `Function0[WifiAccessPoint]`:

```scala
case class WlanHint(
  mac: String,
  signalStrength: Option[Int],
  age: Option[Int],
  channel: Option[Int],
  signalToNoiseRatio: Option[Int]
) extends Function0[WifiAccessPoint] {
  def apply(): WifiAccessPoint = {
    // same body as asWifiAccessPoint in previous snippet
  }
}
```

This would then allow you to write:

```scala
val accessPoint = WifiAccessPoint("00:01:02:03:04:05", None, None, None, None)()
```

Comment: I'm curious: why make the case class extends `Function0` vs. `apply` method in the companion object?

Comment: Easy guaranteed serializability and the easy ability to inspect/clone the arguments would be the main benefits over a companion `apply`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks good. except the fact that it relies on an assumption that must not always hold true: "Builders are mutable and call a method on it will return the very same instance".

As each builder method returns the builder again (usually in java this would be the same instance, but if you would write a builder in Scala, you probably would use an immutable class returning it with xyz.copy(field= ...). So I am not that confident with relying on the fact that every builder method returns the same instance.
I like your ideas though to bake it into the case class!